# Using an extension method defined in nested class

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

Consider the following code:

```
1. namespace MyNS {
2.   // A class
3.   public class MyClass {
4.     public string Do() {
5.       return string.Blank();
6.     }
7.     // A nested type
8.     protected static class Helper {
9.       public static string Blank(this string str) {
10         return String.Empty;
11.       }
12.     }
13.   }
14. } /* namespace */
```

However line 5 will cause the program not to compile. I know that in order to use extension methods a static class must be created and its enclosing namespace referenced through `using` directives.

How to achieve this when the static class is a nested class?

Comment: I've come across this before, basically: you can't.  Instead I made my static class `internal` which proved sufficient in my case.

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2011/07/creating-local-extension-methods.html

Comment: Are you calling Blank() on the string type alias instead of a string variable/field?

Comment: Well I understand that the example is trivial but basically the real scenario is more complicated... but basically I am calling it on the type alias... not as a member

Comment: Can you please clarify what you trying to achieve? (since you clearly can't have extension methods in nested class you need to explain what you are willing to give up )

Comment: Actually I wanted to get a self/consistent solution when adding a functionality in one class developed by others... I guess I can make the static class in the same namespace but internal... I just wanted class MyClass to have access to that extension method only. Of course I can make the method a static member of the class itself, but I wanted to underline that method is related to the string class...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It cannot be done. Extensions methods cannot be defined in nested classes.

Although there is not major obstacle to implementing this feature, it does feel rather cumbersome: extension methods inside a nested class seem overkill as they might as well be defined as part of the outer class itself.

Also, it does force you to clearly organized this as extensions to your classes (again, is you must), rather a than part of them.

If you simply want to defined them locally (as in close to other related functionality), you might want to try [SLaks' trick](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/07/creating-local-extension-methods.html) of creating the extensions methods inside a nested namespace declaration, making the class inside this new namespace not longer "nested".

Comment: It would sometimes be nice to be able to do this for organizational purposes in non-static classes when the only reason you are making them extension methods instead of instance methods is to get around a limitation, i.e. can't have two methods that only differ by generic constraints. In this case I would put them in a nested `public static class` named  `ClassExtensions` and `StructExtensions` so they could access the outer type's private fields.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  For the method to be an extension method it needs to be in a non-nested class.